# Snowflake: Is it possible to intentionally fail a Task conditionally depending on Stream contents?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As part of our data pipeline, we have some Snowflake Tasks with conditional merge statements that update tables. For some known conditions (e.g. table truncates) we want the Task to fail/exit intentionally; however, in reading the docs on Tasks and Merges, I can't seem to find a way to intentionally fail the task.

Therefore, is it possible to intentionally fail a Snowflake Task conditionally? We have SNS automated alerts set up for these Tasks if they fail, so we'll be alerted of these failures.

Additionally, this intentional error should also take advantage of the `when SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA` (docs [link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_stream_has_data)) in order to avoid spinning up warehouse needlessly, avoiding burning of credits. The error should only ever take place when the stream has data.

I've tried some hacky solutions such as putting uninstantiated variables into the if-condition when the particular condition is met, but these have all caused the first instance of the task to fail, regardless of whether or not the condition is met.

Example of current code:

```
create or replace task my_task
    schedule = '1 MINUTE'
    user_task_timeout_ms = 3600000
    suspend_task_after_num_failures = 1
    error_integration = SNS_FAILURE_HERE
    when SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('my_stream')
    as
        merge into my_target_table as target_table
        using (
                select * from my_stream
                qualify row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp) = 1
            ) as stream
            on target_table.timestamp

        -- TRUNCATE
        when not matched and stream.operation_key = 't'
                then THROW ERROR HERE
        -- DELETE
        when matched and stream.operation_key = 'd'
                then delete

        -- UPDATE
        when matched and stream.operation_key <> 'd'
                then update ...

        -- INSERT
        when not matched and stream.operation_key <> 'd'
                then insert ....
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a view that tells you whether to run the task or not?  If you can, then you could create a stream on top of that view and use that in your WHEN clause.

Comment: @MikeWalton: Thanks for the input! I think this would satisfy the main requirement but would still require a warehouse spin-up for every task execution, which would cost quite a bit of Snowflake credits.

Comment: Why?  It'd still be using the STREAM_HAS_DATA function as your WHEN clause.

Answer (score 0):

Keep Runtime error in if block.
E.g.In Below task fails when 1st if condition is met, else it completes successfully.

```
create or replace task test_task
  warehouse=compute_wh
  as
  BEGIN
  IF(1=1)
  THEN
      SELECT 1/0;
  END IF;

  IF (2=2)
  THEN
      SELECT 'Other stuff';
  END IF;
  
  END;
```

Comment: It looks like this method doesn't take advantage of Snowflake's [SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_stream_has_data), so it would "[start] or [resume] a warehouse unnecessarily." I'll modify the question to clarify further!

Answer (score 0):

After going around in circles, our team decided to have an `insert` take place into the target model so that downstream tests alert us on certain conditions, without burning excess compute on the task itself.

The original question was too lofty, so we're punting the alerts to a more robust downstream process in order to keep the task simple.